# Angular post method to php

Tags: php, angularjs, lumen

I've been trying to post data from angular to php all day but I feel quite stuck. 
This is my method from angular controller:

```
function submit() {      
        var JSONObject = {
             "name":$rootScope.name,
             "surname":$rootScope.surname,
             "email":$rootScope.email,
             "review":$rootScope.review
        };
        debugger;
        var Results = UniversalService.PostReview(JSONObject);
    }
```

then it goes to UniversalService where my $http.post method is:

```
function PostReview(JSONObject) {
        debugger;
        $http.post('http://localhost:8000/creation', JSONObject).then();
        debugger;
    }
```

it goes well until this point when it has to send data to php (my web api service is with Lumen framework)

in my DatabaseController.php I expect to recieve my json object (I am quite beginner so I expect that's where I fail)

```
public function created(Request $request)
{
    $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $input= json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE ); //convert JSON into array

    print_r(json_encode($input));
   /* $user=[
        'name'=>$request->input('name'),
        'surname'=>$request->input('surname'),
        'email'=>$request->input('email'),
        'review'=>$request->input('review'),
    ];
    $time=$this->getTime();*/
 //  return DatabaseModel::newUser($user);

}
```

in routes.php

```
$app->post('/creation', [ 'as'=>'creation','uses'=> 'DatabaseController@created']);
```

I used both get and post here out of desperate and I just can't seem to get it right at all. Also in routes.php I enabled header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); and I am not sure if I have to do that (and how) in angular side.

what I get is bunch of errors[image]

But postman seems to work, I have additional function there and when I enter: http://localhost:8000/creation to postman I get null for json object and time from another function that I call in creation()

Comment: You're `post`ing to a `get` URL

Comment: I changed `get` to `post` in routes.php and still have issues :(

Comment: Show your errors with both the js and route having post.

Comment: I added additional photo

Comment: Odd that you're still getting a 405 method not allowed, though why are you viewing that URL in your browser?

Comment: I'm so confused that I do everything:((( Can't get it right

Comment: Now that both are post, try submitting your data through angular again. What happens in your error console?

Comment: I updated image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem today with three other programers. As @jheimbouch said, the problem was that Angular sends OPTIONS method to php service. Another problem as stated was cors. Our solution was:
in /bootstrap/app.php we added:
 `$app->middleware(['Cors' => App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class]);`

then in /Http/Midleware added file CorsMiddleware.php which solved all my problems:

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class CorsMiddleware {

```
protected $settings = [
            'origin' => '*',    // Wide Open!
            'allowMethods' => 'GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS'];

protected function setOrigin($req, $rsp)
{
    $origin = $this->settings['origin'];
    if (is_callable($origin))
    {
        // Call origin callback with request origin
        $origin = call_user_func($origin, $req->header("Origin"));
    }
    $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin);
}

protected function setExposeHeaders($req, $rsp)
{
    if (isset($this->settings->exposeHeaders))
    {
        $exposeHeaders = $this->settings->exposeHeaders;

        if (is_array($exposeHeaders))
        $exposeHeaders = implode(", ", $exposeHeaders);

        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', $exposeHeaders);
    }
}

protected function setMaxAge($req, $rsp)
{
    if (isset($this->settings['maxAge']))
    $rsp->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', $this->settings['maxAge']);
}

protected function setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp)
{
    if (isset($this->settings['allowCredentials']) && $this->settings['allowCredentials'] === True)
    $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
}

protected function setAllowMethods($req, $rsp)
{
    if (isset($this->settings['allowMethods']))
    {
        $allowMethods = $this->settings['allowMethods'];

        if (is_array($allowMethods))
        $allowMethods = implode(", ", $allowMethods);

        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', $allowMethods);
    }
}

protected function setAllowHeaders($req, $rsp)
{
    if (isset($this->settings['allowHeaders']))
    {
        $allowHeaders = $this->settings['allowHeaders'];

        if (is_array($allowHeaders))
        $allowHeaders = implode(", ", $allowHeaders);

    }
    else // Otherwise, use request headers
    {
        $allowHeaders = $req->header("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    }

    if (isset($allowHeaders))
    $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $allowHeaders);

}

protected function setCorsHeaders($req, $rsp)
{
    // http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png
    // Pre-flight
    if ($req->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
    {
        $this->setOrigin($req, $rsp);
        $this->setMaxAge($req, $rsp);
        $this->setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp);
        $this->setAllowMethods($req, $rsp);
        $this->setAllowHeaders($req, $rsp);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->setOrigin($req, $rsp);
        $this->setExposeHeaders($req, $rsp);
        $this->setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp);
    }
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
        $response = new Response("", 200);
    }
    else {
        $response = $next($request);
    }

    $this->setCorsHeaders($request, $response);

    return $response;
}}
```

Hope this will help someone because it took me ages to get it all done! Anyway, big thanks to everyone who helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting caught by the OPTIONS pre-flight request in chrome. Notice in the console that it is complaining about your "OPTIONS" request and not the POST itself. Without seeing your Server code, here is an example of how to handle it, and the headers that need to be on your response for the OPTIONS pre-flight.

```
// respond to preflights
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
  // return only the headers and not the content
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
  }
  exit;
}
```

A more thorough explanation, (and where I grabbed the snippet) can be found here: https://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working